# "It takes two to tango" in German

Tags: idiom

Is there an appropriate translation or an equivalent phrase for "[it takes two to tango](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takes_two_to_tango_%28idiom%29)" in German?

Gibt es eine passende Übersetzung oder eine äquivalente Redewendung für "[it takes two to tango](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takes_two_to_tango_%28idiom%29)" in deutscher Sprache?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Normalerweise wird man einfach sagen:

> Dazu gehören immer zwei.

Google liefert hierfür [alle möglichen Varianten](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22geh%C3%B6ren+immer+zwei%22). Vom Tango ist gewöhnlich nur in Übersetzungen aus dem Englischen die Rede, es klingt aber OK: *Zu einem Tango gehören immer zwei*, *Für einen Tango braucht man zwei* u.ä.

In speziellen Fällen könnte auch ein Goethe-Zitat in Betracht kommen:

> Halb zog sie ihn, halb sank er hin.

Comment: Sehr schöne Antwort, besonders das Zitat von Goethe. Ich habe die Google Ergebnisse gesehen, aber ich wollte die Frage trotzem auf GSE stellen, da ich (mit Recht) erwartet habe, dass ich eine ausführlichere Antwort bekommen werde. Danke schön!

Comment: [Zum Zank und Streit gehören immer zwei; hört einer auf, so ist der Zank vorbei.](https://books.google.de/books?id=TROHQZcor9IC&pg=PT261&lpg=PT261&dq=%22geh%C3%B6ren+immer+zwei%22+redensart&source=bl&ots=_iPTQOFqfL&sig=D_IGX48RHHp9WRQKLFL7_gxjyHA&hl=de&sa=X&ei=T5tXVdWUEaPOyQPWrIHYBw&ved=0CFQQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22geh%C3%B6ren%20immer%20zwei%22%20redensart&f=false) - Kannte ich aber bis eben auch nicht.

Answer (score 3):

Der von [chirlu](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/2813/chirlu) in der [Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/23333/5999) genannte Vorschlag ist sehr gut passend.

Zusätzlich würde ich als weitere idiomatische Alternative Folgendes vorschlagen:

> ... kann man nur zu zweit.

Dies lässt sich zum Teil auch implizit ausdrücken durch:

> ... kann man nicht alleine.

([Verwendungsbeispiel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x43rLlJBTAM))